# Generate a enum based on a constant value in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Is it possible to create a enum based on a constant in C++ ?

If my constant value is 5, i want the enumerator to have 5 elements like below

```
typedef enum {
LIC_0,
LIC_1,
LIC_2,
LIC_3,
LIC4,
} licfiles_t;
```

If my constant value is 10, i want the enumerator to be like this instead,

```
typedef enum {
LIC_0,
LIC_1,
LIC_2,
LIC_3,
LIC4,
LIC5,
LIC6,
LIC7,
LIC8,
LIC9,
} licfiles_t;
```

The reason i want this is , i have a constant called  "MaxLicenses" defined to be 30 now and have a corresponding enumerator that has 30 enum values in it. If someone changes "MaxLicenses" to 20 instead, they shouldn't have to bother changing the enumerator as well. That is my fundamental idea.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate licenses?  Isn't a count good enough?

Comment: enums have much more than 30 values, only the number of named constants is what you limit to 30. If all you do is using numbering then I also don't get the point

Comment: what i mean is that 42 is a valid value for `licfiles_t` even though there are only 10 named constants definded. Hence its not clear what you expect to get from what you ask for

Comment: Source file A has MaxLicenses with a value of 30 currently. Source file B that deals with decryption has a enumerator that it loops through. So i need to bring them in sync somehow.

Comment: What kind of information does `LIC_0` provide that `0` doesn't?

Comment: I have simplified the question. My enum actually has a few more files such as LIC_LOCAL, LIC_MAIN etc. But the set of values in the enumerator LIC_0 , LIC_1 til l LIC_29 is dictated by the constant "MaxLicenses". I am finding myself in an awkward situation.

Comment: Side note: in C++, you should not use `typedef` when defining `enum`, a type is automatically defined. And whenever possible, you should consider a stronger `enum class`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand Anon Mail's advice, even though others have tried to hint at the same thing.  Basically, if you had `int license = get_license_value();` you could still do things like `switch (license) { case 4: /* stuff for LIC 4 */ ...; break; case 5: ...; break; }`.  There's not a lot of benefit to using an `enum`, and given you want the enumeration entries to change, it's easier to avoid an `enum`.  If you're dead-set on more type safety, you could create a wrapper type `class License { explicit License(int l) : l_{l} { } int get() const { return l_; } private: int l_; };`

Comment: Can you ever use `LIC_29` in your source code? How would you use it without knowing `MaxLicenses`?

Comment: When would this *ever* be useful? The point of enums is to enable a mapping from (vaguely) human readable identifiers to easily machine usable numbers. If a) your enum identifiers are *actually* numbers (not particularly human readable) and b) they cannot be used by humans writing the code, because whether any particular one of them exists depends on your `MaxLIcenses`, there is absolutely no point to using an enum.

Comment: @badri Do you want something like this maybe: https://gist.github.com/makulik/7963331 ?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. `What kind of information does LIC_0 provide that 0 doesn't?` The information it provides is that `LIC_10` is ill-formed while 10 is not.

Comment: @eerorika How can you ever deduce anything about `LIC_10` by looking at `LIC_0`? You need to look at the type definition to conclude that. But if the definition is generated, you are not supposed to look at it at all.

Comment: *"If someone changes "MaxLicenses" to 20 instead, they shouldn't have to bother changing the enumerator as well."* -- This individual might not have to change the definition of `licfiles_t`, but what about all the places where the enumerators are used? If changing "MaxLicenses" to 20 causes the enumerator `LIC22` to become invalid, wouldn't this individual still need to edit every place in the code where `LIC22` is used?

Answer (score 2):

You can have it if you are willing to change the syntax slightly.

```
  enum class Licence : unsigned {
    LIC_FIXED,
    LIC_FLOATING,
    LIC_MAGIC,
    LIC_NUMBERED
  };
  
  const int MaxLicence = 20;
  
  consteval Licence LIC(unsigned l) {
      if (l >= MaxLicence) throw "Invalid licence";
      return Licence(l+(unsigned)Licence::LIC_NUMBERED);
  }
```

Now you can have:

```
  auto l1  = LIC(1);   // OK
  auto l19 = LIC(19);  // OK
  auto l42 = LIC(42);  // Compile-time error, invalid licence

  auto x = 3;
  auto lx =  LIC(x);   // Compile-time error, x is not a constant
```

If you want to be really fancy you can create a user-defined literal operator so that you can write e.g. `19_LIC` instead of `LIC(19)`.

---

The function `LIC` as is is probably not very useful as is because you don't know `MaxLicence` ahead of time, so you cannot know whether e.g. `LIC(19)` is valid. But you can have it if you really want.

A more useful version probably wouldn't be constebal, but rather convert licence numbers to values of type `Licence` *at run time*, with error reporting when the value is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have number of enumerators to depend on a constant value.

At the cost of complicating the build process, you could use meta-programming: Write a program that generates both the enum definition and the constant definition.

---

Ideally, the constant should be defined as one of the enumerators. This way it must match with the other enumerators:

```
enum licfiles_t {
    LIC_0,
    LIC_1,
    LIC_2,
    LIC_3,
    LIC4,
    MaxLicenses // 5
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates can't be applied to enum items, so you have to play with preprocessor macros. Macros don't allow recursion into themselves, but you can still unroll them for "up to N" solutions. For instance, for up to 128 licenses, you can do this:

```cpp
#define LICD_0
#define LICD_1 LIC_0
#define LICD_2 LICD_1, LIC_1
#define LICD_3 LICD_2, LIC_2
/* ... */
#define LICD_128 LICD_127, LIC_127
#define _LIC(n) LICD_##n /* jump to N unrolls */
#define LIC(n) _LIC(n)   /* to unpack MaxLicenses */
```

`LIC(n)` will generic `N` (`LIC_0` to `LIC_<N-1>`) enum items. You can pair that up with `MaxLicences` like this:

```cpp
#define MaxLicenses 30

typedef enum {
    LIC(MaxLicenses)
} licfiles_t;

static_assert(LIC_29 == 29, "");
//static_assert(LIC_30 == 30, ""); // compile error, LIC_30 not defined
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/b1E1KG

Of course, typing all that out is a pain, so you can write a little program to generate the code:

```cpp
#define MaxSupportedLicenses 128
std::cout << "#define LICD_0" << std::endl;
std::cout << "#define LICD_1 LIC_0" << std::endl;
for (int i=2; i <= MaxSupportedLicenses; ++i) {
    std::cout << "#define LICD_" << i << " LICD_" << (i - 1) << ", LIC_" << (i - 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Boost_PP should be useful if one chooses the macro route.